# Remove indent on single nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am looking to adjust single nodes without adding indent="no".

`<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" html-version="5"/>`

When testing both "normalize-space" and "translate" they work fine, assuming indent is set to no, but the setting affects the complete document.

**Question:**
How can I remove indent on single rows?

You find the code example here:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qaHaQL/1

Below is the same code:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<data
xmlns:base="http://www.example.org/1"
    >
<base:Content book="Alice">
    <chapterOne>
        Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading.
    </chapterOne>
</base:Content>

<base:Content book="Alice">
    <chapterTwo>
        There seemed to be no use in waiting by the little door, so she went back to the table, half hoping she might find another key on it, or at any rate a book of rules for shutting people up like telescopes
    </chapterTwo>
</base:Content>
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:base="http://www.example.org/1"
>

  <!--xsl:output method="html" indent="no" html-version="5"/>-->
  <xsl:output method="html" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/data">
      
      <html>
          <body>
              
              Chapter one:
              
              <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(base:Content/chapterOne)"/>
              
              <!-- Test [1] Use [normalize-space]. Works if adding [indent="no"] -->
              <!--xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(base:Content/chapterOne)"/>-->
              
              <!-- Test [2] Use [translate]. Works if adding [indent="no"] -->
              <!--xsl:value-of select="translate(base:Content/chapterOne, '&#xA;', '')"/>-->
              
              Chapter two:
              <xsl:value-of select="base:Content/chapterTwo"/>
              
          </body>
      </html>

  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current result:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:base="http://www.example.org/1">
   <body>
      
      Chapter one:
      
      Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of
      having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading.
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      Chapter two:
      
      There seemed to be no use in waiting by the little door, so she went back to the table,
      half hoping she might find another key on it, or at any rate a book of rules for shutting
      people up like telescopes
      
   </body>
</html>
```

**Wanted result**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:base="http://www.example.org/1"><body>
              
              Chapter one:
              
              Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading.
              
              Chapter two:
              
  There seemed to be no use in waiting by the little door, so she went back to the table,
  half hoping she might find another key on it, or at any rate a book of rules for shutting
  people up like telescopes
    </body></html>
```

Comment: I am not sure I have understood what you want to achieve. If you output plain text inside of the `body` element together with `value-of`, the white space you have in your stylesheet will be copied through. As for only applying things like stripping or indentation to certain elements, you can use `xsl:strip-space elements="chapterOne"` and XSLT 3 also has `xsl:output suppress-indentation="foo"`. But inside of the same element, unless the you use `xsl:text` to control exactly which text and whitepsace your XSLT outputs, it is hard to have a single setting achieve different results.

Comment: I am producting 6300 lines of XHTML code and the only outstanding issue I have is the cutting of one sentence that splits into 2 rows. To get the result docs approved I need to pass a testbench that complaints about the sentence split. When I correct the the sentence manuallly, I get through the test bench. I remove all the whitespace in stylesheet and secured that XML source file does not contain whitespace on that specific node.

Comment: It is hard to tell where the issue comes from. If my recollection is right, than in some editions and versions of Saxon you get a line wrap, I think you can configure that only in PE and EE.  But I can't tell from your question or your comment whether that is the issue.